# Issue with string to int conversion in C++

Tags: c++, string, programming-languages

I have an application where I get a `vector<string>`. I need to iterate through each element in the vector and see if a value is an integer value.

Although the vector represents strings, few of the elements can contain an integer. I need to figure out which of those elements are integers, and if an element is an integer, I need its value. If an element in the vector is a string, then I just ignore it.

I tried to use `atoi(vector[index].c_str())`, but I have an issue with it. `atoi` returns an integer value if the value contained in the string is an integer. If not, it returns 0

So, consider the following:

```
atoi("Shankar") = 0
atoi("0") = 0
```

and

```
atoi("123") = 123
atoi("123Shankar") = 123
```

So, how do I distinguish between the above shown cases? If this cannot be achieved using atoi, then what is the alternate solution to this problem?

Please assist.

**EDIT**:

I can loop through the string and see if every character is an integer, but that reduces performance, since for m strings with an average of n characters, I need to check m X n times which makes it O(n^2).

is there a better way to solve this problem?

**EDIT2**:

Unfortunately, I cannot use any 3rd party library for this and just use STL

**EDIT3**:

In my application, the vector does not contain any negative integers so I am considering Xeo's solution since sstream does not distinguish between "123" and "123Shankar"

Thanks everyone for your assistance.

Comment: removed C tag as this has nothing to do with C

Comment: My bad! I thought if there is some solution for this in C, then it also exists in C++ and hence put it there. Anyways, thanks for the edit

Comment: _I can loop through the string and see if every character is an integer, but that reduces performance, since for m strings with an average of n characters, I need to check m X n times which makes it O(n^2)._ I don't believe that's a fair characterization of the performance of looping over the _m_ strings of your vector, or of the performance of scanning the _m * n_ characters of your collection of strings.  In each case, it's still a linear scan of your input, and I don't think you can claim it's O(n^2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go through your string and check every character if it's an integer. If not, break out and report false.

```
bool IsDigit(char c){
  return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
}

bool IsInteger(std::string const& str){
  size_t i = 0;
  if(*str == '-') ++i;
  for( ; i < str.size(); ++i){
     if(!IsDigit(str[i]))
       return false;
  }
  // all chars are integers
  return true;
}
```

**Edit**
`atoi` doesn't really do anything else. See this example implementation:

```
int StrToInt(char const* str){
  int ret = 0, sign = 1;
  if(*str == '-'){
    sign = -1;
    ++str;
  }
  while(IsDigit(*str)){
    ret *= 10; // make room for the next digit
    ret += ((*str) - 0x30); // convert char to digit
    ++str;
  }
  return ret * sign;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my question, please let me know if there is an alternate solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Shankar: why is this not a valid solution? atoi does almost the same, but with a bit more complex checks than just "is an integer" i think. Anyway it has to go through the string one character at a time so it will not perform better than this!

Comment: will fail for negative numbers

Comment: @PeterK, I did not say this is an invalid solution. I wanted to know if there is a better solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. I will implement it this way because the istringstream does not distinguish between "123" and "123Shankar"

Comment: @jk. Yeah, it's a simple implementation.

Comment: @Shankar: Sorry for not replying earlier, my internet went boom. :)

Comment: @jk. Edited to enable negative numbers. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using an istringstream

```
int value;
std::istringstream iss(yourvector[i]);
if(iss >> value)
   std::cout<<"value is not null"<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain a bit more on this? Because, I am getting an error: "Undefined structure 'istringstream' in function main()"

Comment: @Shankar You need to include <sstream>, sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: @Shankar I had tried it and I got:
`value is not null
123`  What is your expected output for that case?

Comment: @jonsca: I am getting value is not null for both "123" and "123Shankar"

Comment: @Shankar Yes, as there is a conversion that happens, but it does differentiate between "0" and "Shankar", which is what atoi could not.

Comment: @jonsca, thanks for the reply. But there is not way to check if "123Shankar" != "123", other than looping through each character in string?

Comment: @Shankar Take the length of the string and see if the `tellg()` method of the istringstream matches up with it.  If there are still characters that weren't converted, then there's more than the number in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sscanf:

```
if(sscanf(s, "%d", &i) == EOF){
    // error
}
```

or with c++:

```
string s = "111";
stringstream ss(s);
int i;  
if((s >> i).fail()){
     //error
}
```

Comment: This method does not work for the type "123Shankar". Please let me know if there is a way to detect this.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string intStr("123");
std::string nonintStr("hello");
try {
    int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(intStr); //OK
    int j = boost::lexical_cast<int>("nonintStr); //throws
}
catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast & e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I should not use any 3rd party library. I will have this edited in my question now.

Comment: @Shankar: Why can you not use Boost? Technically, @Xeo's code has come from a third-party, so can you not use that either?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, I am not supposed to use a 3rd party library. Thats is what my professor insists on. Also, @Xeo's code doesn't use any third-party library IMHO

Comment: @Shankar: He meant that I'm the "third-party". ;)

Comment: @Johnsyweb: LOL was that sarcasm? Nice! :)

Comment: @Shankar, Xeo: I'm glad the subtlety was not lost and trust that if Xeo's work is submitted to Shankar's professor, he gets full credit.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, this question is just a very small part of what my professor wants me to do, so no worries ;)

Comment: @Shankar: If you submit Xeo's work to you professor, no matter how small a proportion of your work it is, you must credit him.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, sure! I may even want to credit you for opening my eyes! :P

Comment: @Shankar: LOL was that sarcasm? Nice! :)

Answer (score 2):

The nature of the problem requires scanning each character per string -- at least until a failure occurs. There is no way to magically take the whole string at-a-glance; any character that would cause it to not be a string would have to be discovered first.

If you find a general pattern with your non-strings -- maybe they are always of the form [numbers][letters] -- then you could have a shortcut check of the LAST character of the string first to exit early. For similar functions where performance matters, I test each corner-case first, and one in the direct middle, before iterating over everything.

Here's an example:

```
bool IsStringValidInt( const std::string& str )
{
    if( str.size() == 0 )
        return false;

    if( !isdigit( str[str.size() - 1] ) ||
        !isdigit( str[str.size() / 2] ) )
        return false;

    size_t i = 0;
    if( str[i] == '-' )
        ++i;

    for( ; i < str.size(); ++i )
        if( !isdigit( str[i] ) )
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check each character of each string to see if it is a digit (using[isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/))

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But, is there any other better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to check with `sscanf()` is as follows:

```
int    val;
char   dummy;

if (sscanf(str, "%d%c", &val, &dummy) == 1) {
    ... // "val" contains the string's integer value
} else {
    ... // the string does not contain an integer
}
```

The important thing is that the `%c` component in the format string causes `sscanf()` to report if there is anything *after* the end of the bit that can be parsed as an integer.