# Change from string to number in C++

Tags: c++, string

Sometimes have a tasks for working with string. Often require changing from string to number, or conversely. In Pascal I'm using "str(n,st);" and "val(st, n, c);", usually. Please, write you methods, how to do it in C++(if you can, specify libraries).

Comment: Did you do any research? For `std::string`, you can use `stoi()`

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort to solve the question or even google before asking...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string look here for a reference on string related methods, the ones you're looking for are under the heading "numeric conversions".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/273908/2157640 https://stackoverflow.com/q/4351371/2157640 https://stackoverflow.com/q/5528053/2157640 https://stackoverflow.com/q/1070497/2157640

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ 11 there is a set of functions that convert objects of `arithmetic types` to objects of type `std::string`

```
string to_string(int val);
string to_string(unsigned val);
string to_string(long val);
string to_string(unsigned long val);
string to_string(long long val);
string to_string(unsigned long long val);
string to_string(float val);
string to_string(double val);
string to_string(long double val);
```

and a set of functions that convert objects of type `std::string` to objects of `arithmetic types`:

```
int stoi(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
long stol(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
unsigned long stoul(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
long long stoll(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
unsigned long long stoull(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
float stof(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0);
double stod(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0);
long double stold(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0);
```

There are also some other functions that perform sich conversion that are not listed here by me. For example some of them are C functions that deal with character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::stoi`

```
std::string example = "21";
int i = std::stoi(example);
```

Check this answer out for more information
[c++ parse int from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442658/c-parse-int-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::istringstream is("42");
int answer;
is >> answer;

std::ostringstream os;
os << 6*9;
std::string real_answer = os.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Solution 1:

```
string strNum = "12345";
int num = atoi(strNum.c_str());
cout<<num<<endl;
```

Solution 2:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string strNum = "12345";
istringstream tempStr(strNum);
int num;
tempStr >> num;
cout<<num<<endl;
```